# In Playwright, how can I find the bounding box of an iframe so I can isolate a screen capture?

Tags: playwright

I want to write some tests against our web tools which are presented in a Storybook web UI.  I am interested in capturing a screen shot of an embedded iframe, but I have not been successful in getting the bounding box of the iframe.

I have tried a varity of things, but in most cases when getting a bounding box, the box values returned are undefined.

```
  const iframe = await page.frameLocator('iframe[title="storybook-preview-iframe"]').getByTitle('storybook-preview-iframe');
  const box = await iframe.boundingBox
```

The interface I would have expected available is something like:  `frameLocator('findTheFrame').frame().getBoundingBox()`

But I am not seeing anything like this.  Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the frame from the Page worked for me.

```
const iframe = await page.getByTitle('storybook-preview-iframe')
const box = await iframe.boundingBox();
```